# Specifying days instead of hours in Team Foundation Server 2010 tasks

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to change the tasks in [Team Foundation Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) 2010 to use days instead of hours?

I feel like I have to do a lot of micro-management by using hours instead of days.

Comment: I am not sure how to solve your issue, but I know that most of the templates used in VS 2010 are based on Agile development which plans Tasks in Ideal Hours and Features in Story Points.  It is not so much a micro-management issue as it would be a paradigm shift to using Agile planning/estimation for development.  If a task takes days to complete it should probably be broken down into smaller tasks.

Comment: @Adam, hmm interesting. I didn't see things from that perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change that field by doing the following.
(I'm fairly sure this requires Power Tools to be installed.)

Open Visual Studio.
Click Tools -> Process Editor -> Work Item Types -> Open WIT from Server
Navigate to your collection/project and open the task template.

This will open a new window containing all the information about the task template.
To change the hours into days, click on the Layout tab located in upper left corner.
From there, click on the option titled "Group - Effort (Hours)".
Change the "Label" attribute to be "Effort (Days)".

Now those fields will be shown as being listed in Days instead of hours.
By default, those fields are saved as doubles. I would recommend changing them to integers unless you plan on being that precise. Below I'll tell you how to change them.

Go back to the Fields tab.
Locate the "Remaining Work" item.
Double click it to edit it.
Change the Type field to be integer instead of double.
Repeat the last few steps with the "Original Estimate" and "Completed Work" items.

That should be everything, I hope it helps.

Comment: won't he also have to change reports and such?

Comment: @John: I hadn't thought about that; I have yet to setup reports on my server. I would assume the reporting system would just query the available fields at run time, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @John: After doing some quick research, I don't think that he will have to update anything having to do with reports.

Answer (score -1):

You do need to change the reports. Although it is just the labels and parameter names, the figures used are the same